# I want to be asked for password for mounting drives

Tags: mount, administration, system-settings

In earlier Ubuntu releases (As far as I remember Natty had it) we were asked for password while trying to mount the drive using Nautilus. But in Ubuntu 12.04 (also in 11.10) it is removed. But I want to re-enable that feature.

Question is: How can I re-enable that feature i.e being asked for mounting drive?

Comment: An easy workaround is to just encrypt the drive(s). I have multiple extra drives, internal and external. All are encrypted. If a drive fails or I give it away I don't need to worry about my data ever being recovered. (I don't think this is exactly what you are asking for so posting as a comment...)

Comment: I'm not very concerned with the data. I was just wanted to enable that feature. I can disable mounting of some drive from a user, to whom I've given my computer for a while. thank you for the comment. I may need that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To re-enable that feature, you have to change the default policy. Follow this procedure:

1. Open terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> keyboard shortcut.
2. Type the command below ( you can copy and paste at the terminal )
   and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   ```
   gksu gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla
   ```
3. In the first section, under the heading of `[Mounting, checking, etc. of internal drives]` There will be a line with  `ResultActive=yes`. Change the `yes` to `auth_admin`. The section after modification will look like this

   ```
   [Mounting, checking, etc. of internal drives]
   Identity=unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo
   Action=org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-*;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-ata-smart*
   ResultActive=auth_admin
   ```

   Save the file by pressing `Ctrl-S` and Exit gedit.

The feature is now activated.

Comment: @nitstorm Thanks for the edit. That was crucial

Comment: Most welcome :)